# Meaning of infinity in $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R\cup \{\pm\infty\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus

I know that $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$ mean a real function of $n$ variables and the image is a real number. But what is the meaning of infinity in the following:

> $$
> f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R\cup \{\pm\infty\}
> $$

I also appreciate an example.

Comment: For those who might be interested, when only topological aspects are considered (i.e. don't consider any arithmetic operations), $\mathbb R\cup \{\pm\infty\}$ is the $2$-point compactification of the reals. Interestingly, the $1$-point and $2$-point compactifications are the only compactifications of the reals with a finite remainder (i.e. you add at most a finite number of new points to the reals). See this [13 February 2002 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=367112) for more details.

Comment: Must the reals be finite?  Then this is the closure of the reals, when infinite values are the frontier.  Some authors use $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of the expression $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\},$ is that the codomain of $f$ is the set of all real numbers union the two formal symbols $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ (read "positive infinity" and "negative infinity"). So the output of the function may be a real number, or it may be $\pm \infty.$

The usage of this notion is that for example this may allow you to extend the domain of the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ to include zero, by saying $f(0)=+\infty.$

More importantly, you may talk about for example the $\limsup$ of any sequence. Even divergent sequences have a limit superior if you allow infinity to be a number.

There is a natural topology on the real line with $\pm\infty$ included, called the [extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), where the entire line $[-\infty,+\infty]$ now looks like a closed interval (of infinite length) with its endpoints included. And this function $f$ is even continuous at zero with respect to this topology.

Although the extended real line is not a field or an abelian group, because expressions like $\infty-\infty$ or $\infty/\infty$ are not defined, still this set does allow an extension of some algebraic operations. For example it is consistent to define $\infty+1=\infty.$

Answer (score 2):

More general, $f\colon A\to B$ means that we deal with a function from the set $A$ to the set $B$. In order words, for a function $f\colon\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$, a function value $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ may either be a real number or $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: So how you would define $\infty$?

Answer (score 2):

Formally, one would define $\infty$ as an element that doesn’t belong to the real numbers, e.g., $\infty:=\{\mathbb R\}$.